# if Statement only returns last

Tags: android, if-statement, null

In my app I need to be able to find out which key "page" has data on it what I've done with help is create this

```
Bundle p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData();
if ( p != null )
{
    p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Price").getData();
}
if ( p != null )
{
    p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Price").getData();
}
String price = p.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

however what happens is this will only return the last if statement in this case ("Snow:Price")

How would I go about fixing this issue. I've tried LOTS of different ways already.

The if-statement is placed in an onClick where I'm sending the strings to another activity where I'l put them in my database

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) {

                Bundle t = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData();
                if ( t != null )
                {
                    t = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Post Title").getData();
                }
                if ( t != null )
                {
                    t = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Post Title").getData();
                }
                String title = t.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);

                Bundle p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData();
                if ( p != null )
                {
                    p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Price").getData();
                }
                if ( p != null )
                {
                    p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Price").getData();
                }
                String price = p.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


                String maincat = mWizardModel.findByKey("Main Category").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostPhotosActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("pTITLE", title);
                i.putExtra("pPRICE", price);
                i.putExtra("pCATEGORY", maincat);
                startActivity(i);



        } else {
                if (mEditingAfterReview) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                } else {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }

        }});
```

This may be helpful or I might be doing something wrong within this statement completely.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I guess you want `p == null` instead of `p != null` ? As it is, each line overwrites the result of the previous call.

Comment: Do you instead want the first result? Place `else` before the subsequent `if`s eg. `else if (p != null)`.

Comment: What you haven't tried is using the debugger!  30 seconds to find this problem.  It amazes me that people try to code without a debugger.  Like fixing a car without a toolkit.  And the answer is simple, should be `== null` not `!= null`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
String price = null;
if ( mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData() != null )
{
    price = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
}
else if ( mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Price").getData() != null )
{
    price = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Price").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
}
else if ( mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Price").getData() != null )
{
    price = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Price").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Why the `String price = null;`?

Comment: You can then check if nothing was assigned. It may happen that none of the `if`s' conditions are true.

Comment: Actually one of them has to be true. I'm using this library [Roman Nuriks Wizard Pager](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager) and I've assigned them so that one of them needs to be filled in in order to get to the end.

Comment: I have a feeling that your answer could be correct but as of now it isn't working

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter. It's also because compiler complains if you use uninitialised values. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It's only returning null. :( there are no errors in the code and my app isn't crashing but nothing is showing up in my subsequent activity.

Comment: So are any of those `mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData()` not null? Can you debug and see?

Comment: It only can grab the "Surf:Price" snow and skate are both null

Comment: I'm not sure where it can go wrong. Have you stepped through the debugger?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41733/discussion-between-derek-smith-and-szymon)

Comment: I'm away from my computer now but maybe we'll ba able to chat in about 1 hour

Comment: Actually, won't be able to chat now :(

Comment: alright no problem man thanks for helping me out though! much appreciated heres some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData()` doesn't return null, then your code is just doing this:

```
Bundle p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData();
p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Skate:Price").getData();
p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Snow:Price").getData();
String price = p.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

You're just overwriting p each time.

Comment: If it doesn't equal null then what other choices do I have? something like if >0 ?

Comment: That depends on what you actually want `p` to be.  If you want `p` to be the first valid price, then use `p == null` instead of `p != null` (which is giving you the LAST valid price).  Or use `if else if`s like Szymon mentioned, or instead of `p`, use `mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData() != null`

Comment: when I use `p == null` it just skips to the next `p == null` and doesn't actually execute the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Should you not be checking

```
if(p == null)
```

that way you will not assign an other value to p if it is already assigned a value.
Not sure if want to store all none null p values in price? if so, try making an Arraylist and put all the price values in it like this

```
ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>;
```

... then add something like this every time you assign p to a none null value

```
price.add(p.getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY));
```

Hope this helps? if not tell me more and I will see what I can do.

Comment: @DerekSmith at the moment your code only returns one value if mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData(); is not null. This is done by every time p is not null you are assigning it a new value. Therefore you will only get the value in the last if statement which is the last place you assigned p a value. If you know the exact amount and order of prices you are looking put them in an array and use them later in your intent. if you don't know the amount of prices that will be looked up use an ArrayList as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about how your code will execute.

If `p` is not null after `Bundle p = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData();`, then *both* of your conditionals in your if statements will evaluate to true (`p` is not null at both points in your code).

You likely want to nest those if statements within each other, or check if `p == null` instead of `p != null`, as that logic would make more sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if checking you can set if else checking.